# Does Selecting from XMLNodes Count as 3-Part Naming Convention in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xmlnode

I recently saw a comment from @Larnu highlighting that 3+ part naming on columns will soon(ish) be depreciated. There was a link to a useful article on his website which details about this:

https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/

Specifically, it quotes from the depreciated SQL Server features page on learn.microsoft.com (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The following SQL Server Database Engine features are supported in the
> next version of SQL Server, but will be deprecated in a later version.
> The specific version of SQL Server has not been determined:
>
> | Category | Deprecated feature | Replacement Feature | name | Feature ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Transact-SQL | Three-part and four-part column references. | Two-part names is the standard-compliant behavior. | More than two-part column name | 3 |

My question is does this apply to when using XMLnodes as a column reference? e.g.:

```
SELECT
    XMLNodes.x.value('@time', 'datetime') as Runtime,
    InnerXMLNode.x.value('@currency', 'varchar(3)') as Currency,
    InnerXMLNode.x.value('@rate', 'Decimal(10,7)') as Rate
from
    @xmlFile.nodes('/Envelope/Cube/Cube') as XMLNodes(x)
    cross apply XMLNodes.x.nodes('Cube') as InnerXMLNode(x)
```

I can't find anything specifically excluding XMLnodes, but are they technically still columns? If the depreciated feature does include XMLnodes, how do you do this without 3+ part naming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the 3+ part naming means when you are naming the object names, for example `SchemaName.TableName.ColumnName`, that isn't the case in the above.

`XMLNodes` is the table name, and `x` the column, however, [`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) is a method of the `xml` type (basically a function), not an object. So you are using 2 part naming, and then using a method extension of the `xml` type, just like you are in the `FROM` for `nodes` (`XMLNodes.x.nodes`).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. You put it in easy to understand terms for me!

Answer (score 3):

**No, it is not. It is just invoking a method on that column.**

For example, you can also do

```
CAST(SomeValue AS xml).value(.....
```

and clearly that is not three-part naming

---

[The official grammar for `SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) is as follows

```
<select_list> ::=   
    {   
      *   
      | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.*   
      | {  
          [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]  
               { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID }   
          | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name }   
            | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]  
          | expression  
          [ [ AS ] column_alias ]   
         }  
      | column_alias = expression   
    } [ ,...n ]
```

and although the grammar is not perfect, you can see that `udt_column_name.method_name` is not classed as an extra column name.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I'm was torn between which (yours or @Larnu's) to pick as the accepted one - these are one of those times where I want to tick both!